# How do I get VS Code's auto-indent feature to work with .html.erb files?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, erb

Having enabled VS Code's default auto-indent feature (`"editor.autoIndent": "full"`), when coding HTML files I get correct auto-indent behaviour when pressing enter with cursor between closing and opening tags.

So, if you imagine pipe charater to be cursor, this:

```
<div>|</div>
```

becomes this:

```
<div>
  |
</div>
```

However, when formatting .html.erb files auto-indent is disabled and I get this:

```
 <div>
|</div>
```

How do I enable the auto-indent feature in .html.erb file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you want is currently not supported. There is/was a feature request issue ticket for it on the VS Code GitHub repo: [ERB missing indentation onEnter #46426](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46426), but it got closed as a duplicate of the more general [Script tags new line behaviour #39128](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39128) ticket), which got closed as `wont-fix`.

If you're using the [`rebornix.Ruby`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) extension for extended Ruby language support, then see also this issue ticket for that extension: [.html.erb files don't auto-close or auto-indent HTML like .html files do #747](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/747).